# Probation Period UK and sacking notice

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, contracts, termination

Currently working for a Company, had no negative reviews or anything, in fact not had one meeting with my line manager or anyone to give me a performance review. Have assumed that this is a good thing. I have always felt that they are proud of my work.

The boss of the company is a 70 year old who knows very little about IT and wants things done instantly. When I told him the changes he wanted me to make would take a few weeks, He told me he was disappointed and that he would no longer be using my code.

I was always under the impression that in the UK you HAD to have a valid reason to fail someones probation or to extend it. My mother runs a business, has wanted to fail someones probation but has been told that there has to be valid chain i.e. meetings and a plan put in place so that they can resolve before they are allowed to terminate your contract. This was told to her by Peninsula who are the UKs leading HR people.

Having done some research, it looks like you can end someones probation period and terminate the contract just because? any employers or people had experience with this?

Comment: You're not fired until you are fired. "I won't be using your code" isn't firing you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the UK government site (https://www.gov.uk/dismissal)

> Dismissal is when your employer ends your employment - they don’t always have to give you notice.
>
> If you’re dismissed, your employer must show they’ve:
>
> - a valid reason that they can justify
> - acted reasonably in the circumstances
>
> They must also:
>
> - be consistent - eg not dismiss you for doing something that they let other employees do
> - have investigated the situation fully before dismissing you - eg if a complaint was made about you

...

> You have the right to ask for a written statement from your employer giving the reasons why you’ve been dismissed if you’re an employee and have completed 2 years’ service (1 year if you started before 6 April 2012).

Talk to a lawyer, but your rights are limited until 2 years service.

Comment: Not really, but it isn't too hard, just kangaroo court them into a PIP, then you're pretty much covered.  Once past the 2 years it gets much harder.  Not that I'd ever consider anything like that.